# undefined is not a function evaluating 'this.props.dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux

I try to test redux. I have component Main that redirects to TestRedux. TestRedux componenent make a dispatch and redirects to TestRedux2 when click on a button.

TestRedux and TestRedux2 are the same, I have made a copy/paste, just change values. TestRedux dispatch correctly, but testRedux2 trigger an error.

Do you know what is the cause of the problem ?

```
// TestRedux
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ADD_RES } from "../Constants/action-types";
import {addResa} from "../Actions/actions";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Store from '../Store/store'


const mapStateToProps = state => ({ date: state.date }) 


export class TestRedux extends React.Component {

  render() {
    this.props.dispatch(addResa(1));

    return (
      <View>
         <Button
              onPress={() => {  this.props.navigation.navigate('TestRedux2')  }}
              title='test'
          />

      </View>
    )
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestRedux)
```

```
// TestRedux2
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { ADD_RES } from "../Constants/action-types";
import {addResa} from "../Actions/actions";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Store from '../Store/store'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ date: state.date }) 

export class TestRedux2 extends React.Component {

  render() {
    this.props.dispatch(addResa(2));

    return (
      <View>
         <Button
              onPress={() => {  this.props.navigation.navigate('TestRedux')  }}
              title='test2'
          />

      </View>
    )
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestRedux2)
```

Store is:

`````
import { createStore } from "redux"; // without redux persist
import { persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import resaReducer from "../Reducers/resaReducer";

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage
}

const Store = createStore(persistCombineReducers(rootPersistConfig, {resaReducer}))
export default Store;
````
`````

Comment: So is `this.props` undefined on the render for the TestRedux2? Or is it just `this.props.dispatch`?

Comment: It is this.props.dispatch. Complete error message is undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.dispatch((0,_actions.addResa)(2))')

Comment: Is there any chance the TestRedux2 lives in a different directory from TestRedux? Is the ../Actions/actions still the correct path to the addResa? It could be complaining about the addResa function.

Comment: show how you map your dispatch to props.

Comment: How do you import and use `TestRedux` and `TestRedux2`? I suggest removing `export` from `export class TestRedux2` and only keep `export [default] connect(...)`. If your component depends on `this.props.dispatch`, it's highly unlikely that you're going to need the unconnected version of the component.

Comment: @ageoff: TestRedux and TestRedux2 are in the same directory

Comment: @codekaizer: do you mean how my store is coded ? I edited the question and added it.

Comment: @Maciek Wawro I use react-navigation and in my App Component I use import {TestRedux} from './redux/Components/TestRedux' (same for TestRedux2). If I don't export the componenet I won't be able to import it and navigate, no ?

Comment: @Freddlow: You should import the connected components. Since they are exported as default, what you do is write `import TestRedux from './redux/Components/TestRedux` (note lack of `{ }`) . See "Default Exports" [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Why `TestRedux` works if you use it the exact same way, is still a mystery to me.

Comment: @Maciek Wawro: thanks it works. But I don't understand why it didn't work with { }. I have read -the link you provide but I thought that "default" was just permitting to avoid { } but not it was a problem to keep them

Comment: @Freddlow: `import { Something }` allows you to import "named imports", e.g. `export class Something`. `import Something` allows you to import the default export  , i.e. `export default ...`.

So, in your case, `import { TestRedux2 }` was referring to the class you defined, and `import TestRedux2` was referring to the **new component** created by `connect()`, one based on your class but fetching `this.props.dispatch` from Redux.

Comment: @Maciek Wawro: Thanks. I can't technically close a discussion accepting a comment, but your comments solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch an action or pass null to connect. See if the issue continues.

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestRedux2)`

to

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TestRedux2)`

Comment: I tried export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TestRedux2) as you suggest, but it doesn't change the error